# I can't input when my structure has integer and character variables

Tags: c

The following is my program written in C

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct Book
{
    char Title[80] ;
    char Author[80];
    int Pages;
    int DatePB;
};

struct Book input_book(void)
{
    struct Book b1;
    gets(b1.Title);
    gets(b1.Author);
    scanf("%d" , &b1.Pages);
    scanf("%d" , &b1.DatePB);
    return b1;
}   

int main(int argc , char *argv[])
{
    struct Book b1[3];
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
    {
        printf("Enter Book %d:\n" , i + 1);
        b1[i] = input_book();
        printf("\n");
    }
    for (i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
    {
        printf("Book %d:\n" , i + 1);
        printf("%s\t%s\t%d\t%d\n" , b1[i].Title , b1[i].Author , b1[i].Pages , b1[i].DatePB);
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

And this is the output I get:

```
Enter Book 1:
Five Mistakes
Aaditua
532

Enter Book 2:
Four Mistakes
Aaditya

Enter Book 3:
Nine Mistakes 
Aaditya

Book 1:
Five Mistakes   Aaditua 581983988   532

Book 2:
    Four Mistakes   1   32681

Book 3:
Aaditya Nine Mistakes   1   32681
```

I don't get that. I can input every detail of the First book , while I can't enter integers in the Second and Third Book. Please Help me out with the appropriate answers.

Comment: Don't mix `scanf()` and `fgets()`,and yes, ___don't use `gets()`___.

Comment: `scanf("%d" , &b1.DatePB);` --> `scanf("%d%*c" , &b1.DatePB);` and you input for `DatePB`.

Answer (score 0):

You may  replace;

```
gets(b1.Title);  // gets is deprecated
gets(b1.Author);
```

with

```
fgets(b1.Title,80,stdin);
fgets(b1.Author,80,stdin);
```

> Notice that gets is quite different from fgets: not only gets uses
>   stdin as source, but it does not include the ending newline character
>   in the resulting string and does not allow to specify a maximum size
>   for str

Then put

```
while(getchar()!='\n') // Wasting any unprocessed buffer
  continue;;
```

just after the second `scanf()`. This is for the below reason :

gets() can take empty strings(see the citation above). If your terminal is line buffered, after the second  `scanf()`, when you press enter on the keyboard, that creates an unprocessed `\n` for the `stdin` buffer and this will be consumed by the next `gets()`. In other words the next `b1.Title` will be an empty string. The bad part is that this messes up the whole input sequence afterwards.

**Reference:** [gets](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/gets/)

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately this couldn't solve the error. I am able to enter all details of Book 1, but I cant enter integer details (DatePB and Pages) for Book 2 and 3. Its still the same error

Comment: and by DatePB, i would be entering 201601 (YYYYMM), and that is what I intended to do

Comment: @AadityaMenon : Just made an edit. The loop should be after the second `scanf`

Answer (score 0):

The use of `gets()` function is deprecated, mostly because it may cause buffer overflow. [`fgets()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) is a better option:

> `char *fgets(char *str, int count, FILE *stream)`
>
> Reads at most count - 1 characters from the given file stream and
>   stores them in the character array pointed to by str. Parsing stops if
>   end-of-file occurs or a newline character is found, in which case str
>   will contain that newline character. If no errors occur, writes a null
>   character at the position immediately after the last character written
>   to str. The behavior is undefined if count is less than 1.

A problem can rise if you use it after `scanf`, because `fgets` will read the newline left in the stream by scanf and stop parsing.

An alternative to the solutions posted here in comments and the previous answer is to write your own helper function to read a single line from the stream, skipping trailing newlines:

```
int read_line( char *str, int size, FILE *f ) {
    int ch,
        i = 0;

    --size;
    while ( i < size  &&  (ch = fgetc(f)) != EOF ) {
        if ( ch == '\n' ) {
            if ( i ) {
                // end of line
                break;
            }
            // skip empty lines
            continue;
        }
        str[i] = ch;
        ++i;
    }
    if ( i == size ) {
        // consume any unread char in line
        do {
            ch = fgetc(f);
        } while ( ch != '\n'  &&  ch != EOF );
    }
    str[i] = '\0';
    return i;
}
```

You can also add another function to read numbers:

```
#define NUMBER_SIZE 12

int read_number( FILE *f ) {
    int num;
    static char buffer[NUMBER_SIZE];

    read_line(buffer, NUMBER_SIZE, f);
    if ( sscanf(buffer, "%d", &num) != 1 )
        return 0;
    return num;
}
```

Using those, you can rewrite your program like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define TITLE_SIZE 80
#define AUTHOR_SIZE 80

/* ...define read_line and read_number here...  */

typedef struct
{
    char Title[TITLE_SIZE];
    char Author[AUTHOR_SIZE];
    int Pages;
    int DatePB;
} Book;

void input_book( Book *b, FILE *f )
{
    read_line(b->Title, TITLE_SIZE, f);
    read_line(b->Author, AUTHOR_SIZE, f);
    b->Pages = read_number(f);
    b->DatePB = read_number(f);
}   

int main(void) {
    Book books[3];
    int i;

    for ( i = 0; i < 3; ++i )
    {
        printf("Enter Book %d:\n" , i + 1);
        input_book(&books[i], stdin);
        printf("\n");
    }
    for ( i = 0; i < 3; ++i )
    {
        printf("Book %d:\n" , i + 1);
        printf("%s\t%s\t%d\t%d\n", books[i].Title, books[i].Author,
                                   books[i].Pages, books[i].DatePB);
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

You can also improve the input_book function by adding some user input error checking.

Answer (score 0):

I run your program on Android.
 I could entre the edition year of the first book, but I couldn't entre the fourth element of the second ans third book.
 So I fixed it by adding another    `get`
 in      `input_book` method and it worked fine.

```
struct Book input_book(void)        {     struct Book b1;
    char empty[80];
     gets(b1.Title); 
     gets(b1.Author);
     scanf("%d" , &b1.Pages);
     scanf("%d" , &b1.DatePB);
     gets(empty);

     return b1; }
```